# Html.Raw on Razer Page removing data-src and data-cookieconsent attributes from iframe elements

Tags: c#, html, cookies, razor, iframe

I am invoking Html.Raw on a string that contains an iframe with a data-src and data-cookieconsent attribute used to block the element unless the user has accepted marketing cookies.

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Tekster.Beskrivelse)
```

My input string contains the following iframe:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" data-cookieconsent="marketing" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/0EdLhHFBAEA" frameborder="0" height="360" width="640"></iframe>
```

But the output on my page after Html.Raw has been invoked to render the content is the following:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="360" width="640"></iframe>
```

It seems that my attributes are somehow being removed. What is the cause of this? What can i do to prevent them from being removed. When it contains just the "src" attribute, the iframe is being displayed without issues.

Comment: It's working for as expected for me, at least. Can you expose all the view code? Seems like the result depends on your code before the `@Html.Raw()`.

Comment: Try replacing `allowfullscreen=""` with: `allowfullscreen="true"` since the former is not legal html.

Comment: I discovered an HTML Sanitizer was the culprit. The attributes were being sanitized from the iframe when fetched from the database.